# Phyton Классы При попытке запуска кода выдаёт ошибку missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and 'file'

Tags: python, классы

**Phyton Классы При попытке запуска кода выдаёт ошибку missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and 'file'**

Сама ошибка:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\alexo_q4humrs\PycharmProjects\classes\main.py", line 26, in 
> books.fill_books()
> TypeError: fill_books() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and 'file'

```
from datetime import datetime
f = open('books.txt', 'r',  encoding='utf-8')

class Books:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b_name = ['']*5
        self.b_author = ['']*5
        self.b_date = ['']*5


    def fill_books(self, file):
        f = file.readlines()
        for i in range(1, 5):
            self.b_author = f[i * 3]
            self.b_name[i] = f[1 + (i - 1) * 3]
            self.b_date[i] = (f'{f[2 + (i - 1) * 3]},1,1')
        self.b_author[0] = f[0]
        self.b_name[0] = f[1]
        self.b_date[0] = f[2]

    def get_books(self):
        for i in range(5):
            print(f'{self.b_author[0]} {self.b_name[0]} {self.b_date[0]}')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    books = Books
    books.fill_books()
    books.get_books()
'''
```

Comment: `books = Books` — хорошенько подумайте, что вы делаете в этой строке

Comment: А потом то же самое про строчку books.fill_books()

Comment: @andreymal можно чуть-чуть конкретнее в чём здесь дело?

Comment: @andreymal забыл добавить скобки, спасибо за намёк

Answer (score 0):

**Готовый код**

```
from datetime import datetime
f = open('books.txt', 'r',  encoding='utf-8')

class Books:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b_name = ['']*5
        self.b_author = ['']*5
        self.b_date = ['']*5


    def fill_books(self, file):
        f = file.readlines()
        for i in range(1, 5):
            self.b_author[i] = f[i * 3]
            self.b_name[i] = f[1 + (i - 1) * 3]
            self.b_date[i] = (f'{f[2 + (i - 1) * 3]},1,1')
        self.b_author[0] = f[0]
        self.b_name[0] = f[1]
        self.b_date[0] = f[2]

    def get_books(self):
        for i in range(5):
            print(f'{self.b_author[0]} {self.b_name[0]} {self.b_date[0]}')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    books = Books()
    books.fill_books(f)
    books.get_books()
```